# how to generate URL to make a GET request with parameters to a java servlet from salesforce?

Tags: apex, webservices, httprequest

We are integrating a 3rd party application with salesforce in real-time to retrieve documents. We are trying to open the response from the application in a new browser window and to do that, we need to make a get request with parameters to the application but due to one of the parameters being a PI, we are encrypting the URL parameters and making a request to java servlet. How to generate URL with parameters from salefsorce and make the request? Aalso, how do I receive response and open it in a new window?
I am new to APIs and servlet. thank you for any help. at the moment I do not have code snippet to provide as I am still trying to figure out the right approach.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm

Comment: You will need to make more efforts and read through the REST developer guide. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/ . Use a VF page to make the API call, so that you can view the response in the new tab. Also read for authentication methods to securely authenticate with your application.

Comment: What does this mean? "due to one of the parameters being a PI" What is a PI?

Comment: @MarkPond PI - personal information, SSN and other info.

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty Thank you for your response, basically the response that we will get it self is a content explorer. so no UI is needed to show the response. I just need to open the request in a new browser window and mke the request form where the servlet filter will intercept the request and modify it.

Comment: To put it into other words, I want to generate the URL for making a GET request with querystring parameters and then the servlet filter from our firewall will intercept the request.

Comment: Are you saying that simply putting your URL in a new tab will take care of everything, as it will be similar to a GET call. What challenges are you facing?

Comment: As I am new to this, I am not sure how do I generate an url in Salesforce to make a get request with 2 parameters for ex the url can be like https://host/servlet?username=xxxx&password=xxxx. something like this and http get request will automatically invoke the filter as it will be on my firewall.